# How to add escape key to key command in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to add a escape key to a key command/voice control command in mac OS X?

I want to use this command to exit from things like a 'search form' (like after pressing ⌘F in Chrome).

I could not find a command listed in voice control to do this.

I've ran these searches on google and Super User:

"escape key OS X key command", "add escape key to mac os key command", "how to literally "escape" mac escape key" and have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer: use ⌘-. (command period) instead of escape.

I was able add "⌘-." to the command and it exits the 'search form' in chrome.

Comment: What do you mean by "without closing the window"? Which window is that? Whether I press ⎋ (escape) or ⌘-., the result is the same.

Comment: Oops, got a little confused with close window commands from the 'voice control commands' menu and was accidentally closing the window with the voice control commands, not the exit or ⌘-./escape key. I've edited my question, thanks.